# Set CKEditor4 Value with PHP

Tags: php, ckeditor

How do you set the CKEditor4 value with PHP? I put the variable inside the  tags, but it's not loading the data in there that I'm grabbing from the database.

```
<td class="rightpan">
<textarea name="editor1"><?=stripslashes($descriptionH); ?></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        removePlugins: 'elementspath' 
    });
</script>
```

Can someone help me? Is it something that belongs in the replace() function such as Value : $descriptionH or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td class="rightpan">
<textarea id="editor1" class="ckeditor" name="editor1"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($descriptionH, ENT_QUOTES); ?></textarea>
<script>
$('#editor1').ckeditor(function() {},
    {
        toolbar: [
            ['Source','Styles', 'Format','TextColor','BGColor'],
            ['Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar','PageBreak'],
            ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Scayt'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', '-', 'About'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock']
        ],
        width: 650,
        height: 350
    }
);
</script>
```